# What is the major side product of the reaction between 2-bromo-2-methylpropane and hydroxide ion?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, halides

[image: reaction scheme]

I know that one of the products will be 2-methylpropan-2-ol, arising via a $\mathrm{S_N1}$ reaction. But what else is formed?

Specifically, I am looking for a side product that is gaseous.

Answer (score 7):

On addition of hydroxide to t-butyl bromide there are two competing reactions, substitution and elimination. Depending on the conditions one of these reactions will predominate but both will always be present. If you are taking the $S_{N}1$ as the main reaction then the elimination ($E1$) side product will be 2-methylpropene, which is a gas at room temperatures and pressures.

[image]

Comment: I'd wager that the E1 predominates here, anyway.